# WP7, can I somehow catch touch events on my application tile that in start menu?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

Can I somehow catch touch events on my aplication tile that in start menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [MIX11 sessions](http://live.visitmix.com). This isn't possible in the current version, but the Mango update coming later this year will include a wide range of changes to the live tile APIs.

Answer (score 2):

Let me get this right. You would like to know if users move/flick/touche the tile of your app.

No dice, it is not possible.

Comment: Well.. it would be cool.. i just want to make user to be able to make some "scratches" on my tile.. user just flick on tile and then tile changes...